# Combining Summary with Detail, no pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have detailed data of a person's spending habits. I have created a Week Ending column in order to organize the data by week:

| Name | Week Ending | Date | Amount | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 11/4/23 | 10/30/23 | $7 | Food |
| John Doe | 11/4/23 | 10/31/23 | $40 | Gas |
| John Doe | 11/4/23 | 10/31/23 | $8 | Junk Food |

There can be 1 - 12 charges per name/week.

I have been asked to combine Name & Week Ending to one line and then show the details in columns (I couldn't figure out how to fit all columns into this):

| Name | Week Ending | 1st Date | 1st Amount | 1st Descrip | 2nd Date | 2nd Amount | 2 Descrip | 3rd Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 11/4/23 | 10/30/23 | $7 | Food | 10/31/23 | $40 | Gas | 10/31/23 |

You'll notice no summaries are being performed.

I have reviewed forums and the article here: https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/. However, they all want to use pivot, and I don't believe this problem fits. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Though, as always, I suggest this is a presentation layer issue, *not* a SQL layer issue.